# \uxxxx sequences inside backticks

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I know that, in general, `\uxxxx` sequences are not supported inside backticks. Do you have any workaround to include them (`\uxxxx` sequences) in column names?

To be specific, imagine calculating Body Mass Index and adding units to column names.

Start with

```
dt<-data.frame(
  `Weight [kg]` = runif(5,50,100),
  `Height [m]` = runif(5,1.5,2),
  check.names=F
)
```

and `mutate`:

```
> dt2<-dt %>% 
   mutate(
     `BMI [kg/m\u00b2]`= `Weight [kg]`/`Height [m]`^2
)
```

This produces an error: `Error: \uxxxx sequences not supported inside backticks (line 3)`.

My workaround is like this:

```
> dt2<-dt %>% 
   mutate(
    `BMI [kg/m2]`= `Weight [kg]`/`Height [m]`^2
  ) %>% 
   set_colnames(colnames(.) %>% str_replace('2\\]', '\u00b2\\]'))

> colnames(dt2)
[1] "Weight [kg]" "Height [m]"  "BMI [kg/m²]"
```

It gives me exactly what I want but is not very elegant.

Suprisingly, a bit clearer approach fails:

```
> dt2<-dt %>% 
   mutate(
     `BMI [kg/m2]`= `Weight [kg]`/`Height [m]`^2
   ) %>% 
    rename_all(str_replace, '2\\]', '\u00b2\\]')

> colnames(dt2)
[1] "Weight [kg]" "Height [m]"  "BMI [kg/m2]"
```

So, my question is: can it be done in not-so-hacky way?

And:

- yes, I'm sure, I need `\uxxx` in column names;
- yes, I use them further on graphs;
- no, I don't want to replace them with `expression`'s.

Comment: I answered your question before I read that you don't want to use `expression`s. I deleted that answer, but for future reference, here is the method that works with an expression: `dt %>% 
    mutate(
        !!sym("BMI [kg/m\u00b2]") := \`Weight [kg]\`/\`Height [m]\`^2
    )`

Comment: Thank you, @Bas, maybe it turns out useful someday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using single quotes instead of backticks?

```r
dt %>% mutate('BMI [kg/m\u00b2]' = `Weight [kg]`/`Height [m]`^2)
#>   Weight [kg] Height [m] BMI [kg/m²]
#> 1    67.68154   1.757490    21.91211
#> 2    72.32362   1.817616    21.89151
#> 3    89.28197   1.854459    25.96146
#> 4    52.14819   1.709520    17.84395
#> 5    83.48281   1.969367    21.52502
```

Or double quotes?

```r
dt %>% mutate("BMI [kg/m\u00b2]" = `Weight [kg]`/`Height [m]`^2)
#>   Weight [kg] Height [m] BMI [kg/m²]
#> 1    67.68154   1.757490    21.91211
#> 2    72.32362   1.817616    21.89151
#> 3    89.28197   1.854459    25.96146
#> 4    52.14819   1.709520    17.84395
#> 5    83.48281   1.969367    21.52502
```

You can also use them to access items in your new data frame:

```
dt2$'BMI [kg/m\u00b2]'
#> [1] 21.91211 21.89151 25.96146 17.84395 21.52502

dt2$"BMI [kg/m\u00b2]"
#> [1] 21.91211 21.89151 25.96146 17.84395 21.52502
```

Or did you specifically need to use backticks for some reason?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was not aware of use of single or doble ticks in  this situation. I thought backticks are the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Argument names don't have to be in backticks, they can be regular quoted strings.  So this works fine:

```
dt2<-dt %>% 
   mutate(
     "BMI [kg/m\u00b2]" = `Weight [kg]`/`Height [m]`^2
)
```

It will be hard to refer to that column name in expressions in later code; you'll need to specify the column by number, or use an expression like `dt2["BMI [kg/m\u00b2]"]` (or `dt2$"BMI [kg/m\u00b2]"` as used by @AllanCameron in his answer).  But it will print fine:

```
> dt2
  Weight [kg] Height [m] BMI [kg/m²]
1    51.89918   1.825124    15.58029
2    80.74140   1.602126    31.45595
3    71.35380   1.974187    18.30799
4    64.44167   1.989202    16.28580
5    76.13564   1.886232    21.39922
```

Edited to add:  It's also fine to use

```
`BMI [kg/m²]`
```

anywhere a column name can be used, you just can't encode the special char with `\uxxxx`.

Comment: Your last point isn't true: you can also access the columns using the `$` operator - see my earlier answer.

Comment: @AllanCameron I'd say that's an expression like the one I gave :-).  But I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Aren't these two answers just the same now?

Comment: @AllanCameron:  Yes, they're essentially the same.  Mine has a little bit more theory in it, but yours was posted first, as I was writing it.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted @AllanCameron answer since it was first. To add something to your discussion, use of code completion in RStudio makes referencing to such variable quite easy, I just type `dt2$BMI` and hit Tab.

Comment: What I meant by being more difficult is that you can't have just the name in an expression as you did with the other variables.  But I was wrong, as long as you're adding printable characters:  backticks around `BMI [kg/m²]` are fine.  You'd only have trouble if you're using some weird character that you can't print, and that would kind of make the whole exercise pointless.  So @AllanCameron deserves his checkmark!